# Unable to stop running Python thread

Tags: python, multithreading

I have an application listening on a specific TCP port to handle received requests (`listen.py`). After that, I have another one (`trigger.py`) that depending on the requested parameters triggers the respective operation.

Now, lets say the operation A was triggered (`opA.py`). Operation A uses a worker thread to start (`worker.py`). When the user request `listen.py` to stop operation A, the started thread is supposed to stop.

**UPDATED:**

The problem is that the thread is never stopped since the problem lies in `trigger.py`. The OperationA instance is lost once the code exits. So, I can never call stopOperation since it show me `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'stopOperation'`

Any ideas of How to solve this?

listen.py

```
from trigger import Trigger
'''
code to handle requests here: 
1st: param -> 'start'
2nd: param -> 'stop'
'''
t = Trigger()
t.execute(param)
```

trigger.py

```
from opA import OperationA
class Trigger():
    def execute(param):
        opA = OperationA()
        if param == 'start':
            opA.startOperation()
        elif param == 'stop':
            opA.stopOperation()
```

opA.py

```
from worker import ThreadParam
class OperationThread(ThreadParam):
    def run(self):
        while (self.running == False):
            '''
            do something here
            '''
class OperationA():
    def _init__(self):
        listenThread = OperationThread(self)
    def startOperation(self):
        self.listenThread.start()
    def stopOperation(self):
        if self.listenThread.isAlive() == True:
            print 'Thread is alive'
            self.listenThread.killSignal()
        else:
            print 'Thread is dead'
```

worker.py

```
from threading import Thread
class ThreadParam(Thread):
    def __init__(self, _parent):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.parent = _parent
        self.running = False;
    def killSignal(self):
        self.running = True;
```

Comment: You have this in your example code: `opA = OperationA`. Is this a typo in the example only, or did you forget the `()` in the real code, too?

Comment: @dano it was a typo. Thanks

Comment: Also, I'm confused by this: "Also, when I request the operation to be started, why does the 'Thread is dead' inside the stopOperation() is displayed?" You're saying `stopOperation()` is getting called when you call `execute('start')`? Based on the example code you provided, that doesn't seem possible. Is `stopOperation` called anywhere else that you didn't include here?

Comment: Finally, is the `run` method making any blocking calls that would prevent is from looping back to the top of your `while` loop?

Comment: @dano It also seems impossible to me, but it happens. `stopOperation()` is not called from anywhere else.

Comment: @dano `run` method is not making any blocks

Comment: Put a `print` statement at the top of `execute`; I bet it's being called twice.

Comment: @dano I tested it. I've put a print before the `execute` and it is only printed once.

Comment: @vgo Could you please show actual code that has the described problem.  What you showed still seems to have typos and ommisions, like a missing `_` in `__init__()` and also a missing `self.` in `OperationA.__init__()`.

Also the trigger class is odd.  There you either create an object of type `OperationA` and call the start method without holding on to it somewhere so you can never call the stop method on it.  Or you create a `OperationA` instance and call the stop method on an instance that never was started.  That doesn't make sense.

Comment: @BlackJack that is exactly the problem. The trigger.py needs some kind of looping mechanism. I just don't know how to do it...

Comment: @vgo It doesn't need looping but has to hold on the created `OperationA` instance.  And probably preventing the creation of more than one.  Executing 'stop' then has to stop the instance created when 'start' was given instead of creating a new instance that never was started and trying to stop that.

Comment: @vgo I think that the core problem is that you should have two process, one in background which run what ever you want,
the other one which communicate with the first depending on command line parameter. You can use nearly any [Inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) to communicate between both process

Answer (score 0):

A minimal useful `Trigger` might look like this:

```
class Trigger(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.operation = None

    def execute(self, command):
        if command == 'start':
            assert self.operation is None
            self.operation = OperationA()
            self.operation.start_operation()
        elif command == 'stop':
            self.operation.stop_operation()
            self.operation = None
        else:
            print 'Unknown command', repr(command)
```

Comment: thanks for the help. I tried your suggestion but it seems that the instance gets lost. When I run the code it shows `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'stop_operation'`

Comment: @vgo Then you've tried 'stop' before 'start'.  It did not get lost, it wasn't there in the first place.  Or you tried two stops without a start in between.

Comment: @vgo Apparently not on the same `Trigger` instance you used 'stop' afterwards.  Otherwise `self.operation` would not be `None`.